# Upgrading Galaxy i7500 to OS 2.x

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-i7500

I have a Samsung Galaxy i7500. The OS version is 1.5, and I believe Samsung did not publish any updates (other than a 1.6 (Donut) in one country).

Is there any way to upgrade my phone to Android 2.x?

There's [gaosp](http://code.google.com/p/gaosp/). but the warning "Don't complain if your phone doesn't boot up!" is a bit disenchanting.

Comment: I'm afraid that's probably your only option. Older Android phones are put out to pasture pretty readily.

Comment: @AlEverett that's what I fear as well. It wouldn't be so bad, except that most apps require 2.x to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAOSP is your only option. It's in beta 3, so it's a pretty sure bet.